# Where to place the javascript code for content page in ASP.NET when using the master page

Tags: asp.net

I want to use a image slider in my web page, the problem is that when I use the JS code with the master page it doesn't work, it works for page without master page. I tried placing the JS code in master page head section and in the content page in 

, neither works.

I am using below js code.

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var i = 1;
        function fun() {
            i++;
            document.getElementById("img1").src = "images/" + i + ".jpg";
            if (i == 4) //here 2 is number of images i want to display in the slide show
            { i = 0; }
        }
        setInterval("fun()", 2000);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asp:Image I am almost sure that your problem is with the ids.

Master Page implements the [INamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  interface, so Controls inside a Page with a Master Page are rendered with a nested id. Something like:

```
<img name="ctl00$MainContent$img1" id="ctl00_MainContent_img1" />
```

against what you get in a Page without Master Page

```
<img name="img1" id="img1" />
```

It is done this way to guarantee the ids of the controls to be unique within an entire application.

> Any control that implements this interface creates a new namespace in which all child control ID attributes are guaranteed to be unique within an entire application. The marker provided by this interface allows unique naming of the dynamically generated server control instances within the Web server controls that support data binding.

You can get the ClientID of a control in Page with the [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Your code will look something like:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;
    function fun() {
        i++;
        document.getElementById("<%= img1.ClientID %>").src = "images/" + i + ".jpg";
        if (i == 4) //here 2 is number of images i want to display in the slide show
        { i = 0; }
    }
    setInterval("fun()", 2000);
</script>

<asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" />
```

You can also can set the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your control to Static when declaring it and it will keep the id you assigned:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;
    function fun() {
        i++;
        document.getElementById("img1").src = "images/" + i + ".jpg";
        if (i == 4) //here 2 is number of images i want to display in the slide show
        { i = 0; }
    }
    setInterval("fun()", 2000);
</script>

<asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

But be warned that you have to do all the work to assure that the ids are not duplicated if you use this last method.

Answer (score 0):

It does not worki because probably the ID of the control you are trying to get using `getElementById` is different when it get rendered on the page.

more info [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22111/Master-Pages-and-JavaScript-document-getElementByI)

I would not use this approach anyway because you could have cross-browser issue.

I would use a JQuery plug-in instead

Answer (score 0):

When you use masterpage, all aspxcontrols name change (when it get rendered)

if you wanna reach some controls, you have to use **controlname.ClientID**